# Making sparse matrix using awk

Tags: bash, matrix, text, awk, editing

I am having trouble formatting a large 2D matrix into a "sparse matrix" format. I hope someone here can help.

Due to the large file size, an *awk* script should be prefered.

Here is a hypothetical set from the data (tab delimited):

```
Regions      string8-0      string8-5000      string8-10000
string8-0        0                2.1                1.15    
string8-5000     0                0                  2.4  
string8-10000    0                4                  3.1
```

So, the resulted output should be a tab separeted file with four columns. **Column1** = the numeric part of rownames (colomn1 from data; example: 0, 5000, 1000); **Column2** = is the corresponding numeric part of the colnames (example: 0, 5000, 10000), **Column3** = the value between the two bin. **Column4** = string part of column names (string8, string8, string8).

And only print this if the corresponding value is not zero.

like this:

```
0      5000    2.1    string8
0      10000   1.15   string8
5000   10000   2.4    string8
10000  5000    4      string8
10000  10000   3.1    string8
```

Sorry, if it is a redundant question, but I could not find any solutions.

Thanks,
Laszlo

Comment: You say you are having trouble --- what have you tried and what trouble in particular are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Now outputs separate lines for multiple "hits" in input row

```
$ cat sp.awk
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }

NR == 1 {
    for (c=2; c<=NF; ++c) {
        split($c, col_parts, "-")
        col_str[c] = col_parts[1]
        col_num[c] = col_parts[2]
    }
    next
}

{
    split($1, parts, "-");
    col1 = parts[2]
    for (c=2; c<=NF; ++c) {
        if ($c != 0) {
            print col1, col_num[c], $c, col_str[c]
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f sp.awk sp.txt
0       5000    2.1     string8
0       10000   1.15    string8
5000    10000   2.4     string8
10000   5000    4       string8
10000   10000   3.1     string8
```

Comment: I'm sure we can do that, though I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Edit your question to show sample input and the desired output that demonstrates this requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! However, how can I add a new line after each hit?

So, based on that example it work perfectly, but in the case if one row has multiple "hits", it prints those hits in one row. I would like to print each hit in new line. I edited the printf part of your code (now it prints the hits in new line, but without the column1 information, and leaves a blank line after it switches to the next element)

Comment: Edit your question to include at least some sample data with multiple hits and show the desired output.

Comment: [link](http://tinyurl.com/zrk9ta4) Here I attach the result. Basicly I just want to fill the empty column1 values. (like 0,0,0,40000,40000,40000,40000, etc)

Comment: Formatting doesn't work in comments. Edit the original question itself.  Your sample data and desired output need to account for the possibility of multiple hits. Otherwise, new people coming to the question (today or a year from today) won't have a full understanding of what needs to be done (as I didn't) or what problem the answers are really solving.

Comment: I formatted the original question, and with slight edit with your code, I could do it. I just needed to put the first print command into the for cycle, and remove the last print (print "") command. 
Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Well done! Thanks for updating the question. That way we can make the site as useful as possible for those who follow. I've updated my answer as well to account for the multiple hits.